# How to put specific value on bottom in Order By Asc?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with list of some names and I selecting it in ascending order.

For example :

```
names
======
Apple

Ball

Cat

Dog
```

How can I put the `'Ball'` on the bottom in ascending order list so the list appear like this :

```
names
======
Apple

Cat

Dog

Ball
```

How can I achieve it in sql query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `CASE` in the `ORDER BY` clause

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Names = 'Ball' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
         Names
```

Here's a [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/817671/1)

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly.